# Qt Gui Application background color stylesheet

Tags: c++, css, qt, user-interface, stylesheet

I want to set background color for my form

like this

```
body
{
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

I am using QWidget selector but i only want to change window background;

And how i can ise one stylesheet for all windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set specific style sheets for any `QWdiget`. If it is your main window you can do:

```
QString style = "QMainWindow { background-color: #fff; }";  // or other color
this->setStyleSheet(style); // assuming you are calling from the QMainWindow inherited class
```

You can do the same to a single widget in the main window, for instance to a `QLabel` instantiated as `label`:

```
QString style = "QLabel { background-color: #fff; }";  // or other color
label->setStyleSheet(style);
```

You can also target all child widgets of another or specify a single child widget. Take a look at http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/stylesheet-examples.html